# Intellisense for OpenSource libraries

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++-2013

In my VS2013 C++ project I use 3rdparty libraries of which I have the full source code available. I am able to

- Jump directly into header files of said library to the *declarations*
- Link the sources with the pdb files so I can jump in the 3rdparty source code while debugging.
- Find library functions using "Navigate-To" (Ctrl+Comma)

Is there a way to use the full Intellisense potential at **coding time**, e.g.

- Jump to the cpp files, i.e. the *definition* of library functions like I am able to while debugging?
- Toggle between header and source file inside the library ?

Comment: It is a very simple rule, the parser only parses source files that it knows about.  That requires them to either be #included in existing source files in your project, what you have now, or the files to be part of a project, what you don't have right now.  So add a project for the library and add it to your solution.  Works best if the project can actually build.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I don't get the first option: of course, the headers are included in existing source files right now, but the cpp files cannot be found. So I reckon the second option is the only possible way?